# one side of image as plane is normal, the other is white

Tags: materials, image, transparency

I believe this has something to do with the translucent shader but I'm not sure.

[image: ShadingProblem]

Answer (score 0):

Your plane is white on one side because of light shading. If you do not want your plane to be affected by light, set the Specular of the Principled BSDF to 0. This makes the plane not reflect any light.

Comment: I've tried reducing specular and increasing roughness. Neither of those appear to work

Comment: @trburns does the "whiteness" move around when you move your camera like it's light?

Comment: it does so you were correct it does have something to do with the lighting. but changing the specular isn't fixing it unfortunately